# Is this ODE system solvable? (non-constant but simple coefficients)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$
f''=x^4(k_1\ f-k_2\ g) \\
g''=-x^4(k_1\ f-k_2\ g)
$

with $k_i \in  \mathbb{R}$

So the coefficients are not constant, but the simple form maybe allows an analytical solution?

Comment: Use power series representation of $f$ and $g$, and use the ODEs to obtain the coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maple produces the solution
$$\eqalign{ f \left( x \right) &=c_{{1}}+c_{{2}}x+c_{{3}}\sqrt {x}{{\; J}
_{1/6}\left(1/3\,\sqrt {-k_{{1}}-k_{{2}}}{x}^{3}\right)}+{ c_4}\,
\sqrt {x}{{\; Y}_{1/6}\left(1/3\,\sqrt {-k_{{1}}-k_{{2}}}{x}^{3}
\right)},\cr g \left( x \right) &=-{\frac {c_{{3}}\sqrt {x}{{\; J}_{1/6
}\left(1/3\,\sqrt {-k_{{1}}-k_{{2}}}{x}^{3}\right)}k_{{2}}+{c_4}
\,\sqrt {x}{{\; Y}_{1/6}\left(1/3\,\sqrt {-k_{{1}}-k_{{2}}}{x}^{3}
\right)}k_{{2}}-xc_{{2}}k_{{1}}-c_{{1}}k_{{1}}}{k_{{2}}}}}
$$
where $c_i$ are arbitrary constants and $J_{1/6}$ and $Y_{1/6}$ are Bessel functions of the first and second kinds.

For some reason it's writing the solution in a way that's most appropriate when $k_1 + k_2 < 0$.  For $k_1 + k_2 > 0$, you can write this as

$$\eqalign{
f \left( x \right) &=c_{{1}}+c_{{2}}x+c_{{3}}\sqrt {x}{{\; I}
_{1/6}\left(1/3\,\sqrt {k_{{1}}+k_{{2}}}{x}^{3}\right)}+c_{{4}}\sqrt {
x}{{\; K}_{1/6}\left(1/3\,\sqrt {k_{{1}}+k_{{2}}}{x}^{3}\right)}\cr g
 \left( x \right) &=-{\frac {c_{{3}}\sqrt {x}{{\; I}_{1/6}\left(1/3\,
\sqrt {k_{{1}}+k_{{2}}}{x}^{3}\right)}k_{{2}}+c_{{4}}\sqrt {x}{{\; K}
_{1/6}\left(1/3\,\sqrt {k_{{1}}+k_{{2}}}{x}^{3}\right)}k_{{2}}-xc_{{2}
}k_{{1}}-c_{{1}}k_{{1}}}{k_{{2}}}}}
$$
where $I_{1/6}$ and $K_{1/6}$ are modified Bessel functions of the first and second kinds.

Comment: Ok thanks. I should have Wolfram it quickly instead of asking.